# Using yield from a block duplicates the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with a method where the goal is to output something if it exists, otherwise yield the code in the block. Pretty straightforward, but it's easier to grok with an example:

In my partial I have the following:

```
<%= @item.output do %>
  Default output
<% end %>
```

And my model:

```
def output
  return "Override the default" if override?
  yield
end
```

If `override?` is true, this shows "Override the default" in the view the way I want it to. However, if it's false, the entire partial gets duplicated and inserted where "Default output" text should be! That's what happens if I use `<%= %>`.

However, if I use `<%- %>` instead, when `override?` is true it outputs nothing, but when it's false it shows "Default output" as it should.

The result I want is for the code in the partial to execute the code in the block (in this case, "Default output") when `override?` is false, and execute the code in the block when it's true. In standard Ruby, it works as it should:

```
irb(main):001:0> def test(bool)
irb(main):002:1>   return "Method" if bool
irb(main):003:1>   yield
irb(main):004:1> end
=> :test
irb(main):005:0> 
irb(main):006:0> test(true) { "Block" }
=> "Method"
irb(main):007:0> test(false) { "Block" }
=> "Block"
```

But Rails is apparently doing some ^%$# with `yield` and views so it's not working out how I want it to whether I use `-` or `=` in my partial to render the code.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that simply changing `yield` to `puts yield` makes things work as intended. I guess Rails yields the yield. Wat.

Answer (score 0):

Remove = from <%= @item.output do %> by changing it to.                 <% @item.output do %>

Comment: That doesn't work either, I noted it in my post where I wrote "However, if I use <%- %> instead, when override? is true it outputs nothing, but when it's false it shows 'Default output' as it should". Essentially, it gives me the reverse of the problem. I did find the solution, which was to use `puts yield` instead of `yield` in my model. Go figure.